# New to MS Access as well as coding and trying to build an IFF statement

Tags: vba, ms-access

status:

```
IIf([Ongoing]=True,"Ongoing",
   IIf([DueOut]![Completed]=True,"Completed", 
     IIf([DueOut]![Suspense]<Date(),"Overdue",
        IIf(DateDiff("d",Date(),[Suspense])<6,"This Week",
           IIf(DateDiff("d",Date(),[Suspense]) Between 7 And 14,"Next Week","Greater than 2 Weeks", 
               IIf([Suspense]>30,date(),"greater than 30 days")
           )
         )
       )
    )
```

I keep running into errors trying to add the "greater than 30 days" aspect.

Comment: BTW if you expect `[Ongoing]` to have a `True/False` value you can just use: `If [Ongoing] Then` (for example) instead of `If True = True Then` (used If-Then for ease of explanation)

Comment: Shouldn't `[Suspense]>30` involve a `DataDiff`?

Comment: status: IIf([Ongoing]=True,"Ongoing",IIf([DueOut]![Completed]=True,"Completed",IIf([DueOut]![Suspense]<Date(),"Overdue",IIf(DateDiff("d",Date(),[Suspense])<6,"This Week",IIf(DateDiff("d",Date(),[Suspense]) Between 7 And 14,"Next Week","Greater than 2 Weeks",IIf(DateDiff(("d",[Suspense],Date()>30,"Greater than 30 days")))))

Comment: What I am trying to do is return to the user if the suspense date is over 30 days from current date "Greater than 30 days"

Comment: Your second-to-last `Iif` seems to have 4 arguments: there should only be 3

Comment: Everything works and displays as supposed to until the last Iff statement. The last statement wont display that suspense date is over 30 days.

Comment: @EricSchneider, please explain what `iif` statement does (not a joke question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, don't nest that many `IIF` statements when you can just use the [CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/switch-function) function.

```
CASE([Ongoing]=True,"Ongoing",
[DueOut]![Completed]=True,"Completed", 
[DueOut]![Suspense]<Date(),"Overdue",
DateDiff("d",Date(),[Suspense])< 7,"This Week",
DateDiff("d",Date(),[Suspense]) < 14,"Next Week",
DateDiff("d",Date(),[Suspense]) < 30, "Greater than 2 Weeks"
True, "Greater than 30 days")
```

(also fixed some syntax)

Comment: I do agree.  `CASE` is cleaner.

Comment: Thank you everyone! I do appreciate the feedback, and both solutions worked great!

Answer (score 1):

Just syntax errors... Your second-to-last `IIf` statement has *four* arguments the way you wrote it.  It appears that when you stuck your last `IIf` in there, you just didn't properly integrate it into the previous one.  Try this:

```
IIf([Ongoing],"Ongoing",
   IIf([DueOut]![Completed]=True,"Completed", 
      IIf([DueOut]![Suspense]<Date(),"Overdue",
         IIf(DateDiff("d",Date(),[DueOut]![Suspense]) <6,"This Week",
            IIf(DateDiff("d",Date(),[DueOut]![Suspense]) <14,"Next Week",
               IIf(DateDiff("d",Date(),[DueOut]![Suspense]) <30, "Greater than 2 Weeks", 
                  "Greater than 30 days"
               )
            )
         )
      )
   )
)
```

Now that it works syntactically, I would question your logic though.  For the projects that are still due (this week, next week, etc.) are they also `Ongoing`?  If so, the logic will never reach the "this week/next week" section of code.  It will simply return "Ongoing".  If I misunderstand how the `Ongoing` flag is used, then you're probably alright, but if--by being "ongoing"--you want to show when they're due, then you would never want it return "Ongoing".  You would either want "Completed", "Overdue", or a description of when it *is* due.  *If that is the case* (and I'm not sure if it is), then try this:

```
IIf([DueOut]![Completed],"Completed", 
   IIf([DueOut]![Suspense]<Date(),"Overdue",
      IIf(DateDiff("d",Date(),[DueOut]![Suspense]) <6,"This Week",
         IIf(DateDiff("d",Date(),[DueOut]![Suspense]) <14,"Next Week",
            IIf(DateDiff("d",Date(),[DueOut]![Suspense]) <30, "Greater than 2 Weeks", 
               "Greater than 30 days"
            )
         )
      )
   )
)
```